# Exposing CORBA Services as Web Services with Apache CXF?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, apache-axis, corba

With Axis2 you can expose a CORBA Service as Web Service as described in the docs:
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/corba-deployer.html

Is this possible with CXF, too? There are Corba samples, but as I understand, they are a Web Service clients that internally go to a Corba Server, which is never exposed as Web Service, is it? 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/corba/

Comment: We have created some web services exposing CORBA services using r2corba which makes it easy to call CORBA services from a Ruby on Rails environment.